# How do I override a website/domain using Sockets?

Tags: java, sockets

I was recently messing around with `Sockets`, and I realized that you can not only send Data through a `DataOutputStream` using `Sockets` and `ServerSockets`, but you can also type "`localhost:[port]`" into your browser which will also connect to the `ServerSocket` and display whatever the `ServerSocket` returns on the webpage.

Seeing this it made me wonder if it is possible to check if someone on my network is going to a specific URL, say `google.com` and instead of connecting to `Google`, just display custom content on the screen.

If this is possible, then please do tell me, I do understand that it is very possible that this does not work in Java, but instead somehow else, and if anyone knows any other way, then that would be very much appreciated as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack). In general, this might be possible to do even in Java, if you will use a JNI library, which could put your network card into [promiscuous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode), then you have to intercept all DNS requests and respond with custom IP address, which will point to your server.

Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

The domains are resolved into IP addresses by a resolver, which gets this answer from a DNS server.

For mapping something like google.com to your own IP address, one would need to hack into one of those (for your internal network ) and prevent the queries from going out to the google nameservers; and instead return a custom or local IP address. Specifically, these techniques when tried on public internet are called **man in the middle** attack, and there are security measures like https and DNSSEC that could alert the end user that they are being served by a fake website.